# Need spaces between 1-st and 4-th 25% inline-block

Tags: css, spacing

How can i set spaces between the first and the last 25% inline-block div's in one row?

As i know it's easy to do in flex, using {justify-content: space-between;} command, but i want to find solution for inline-block elements.

Thanks!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrap {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
.wrap > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What spacing are you wanting? If the blocks are 25% wide, 4 of them will fill the container.

Comment: don't answer your question within the question. Either add your own answer or delete the question.

Comment: Sure. It's done

Answer (score 0):

**UPD** Solution was found - 'calc' function to calculate margin between elements. Thanks to [Andrey Fedorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/208243/andrey-fedorov). See the code below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

:root {
  --marginSize: 20px;
}

.wrap > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(25% - var(--marginSize) * 3 / 4);
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.wrap > div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: var(--marginSize);
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
```